# Django renders information to wrong database field

Tags: python, django

so I was implementing a database in Django to take in username and password using the given Users model. However, when I hit submit the password gets taken into the email field. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong? This is for user signup. Thank you! could it be that Users does not come with a passwords section? How would I Add that in?

forms.py

```
   class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(
            required = True,
            label = 'Username',
            max_length = 32
        )
        password = forms.CharField(
            required = True,
            label = 'Password',
            max_length = 32,
            widget = forms.PasswordInput()
        )
```

views.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
#from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

#from . import views
# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def profiles(request):
    return render(request, 'profiles.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            print(userObj)
            username = userObj['username']
            password =  userObj['password']
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
                User.objects.create_user(username,password)
                user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
                login(request)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that email or password already exists')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup_form.html', {'form': form})

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login</title>
  {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'signup.css' %}">
  </head>
<body>
</div>
<div class='login'>
  <div class='login_title'>
    <span>Sign Up</span>
  </div>
  <div class='login_fields'>
    <div class='login_fields__user'>
      <div class='icon'>
        <img src='http://d2nysvt2e2u12u.cloudfront.net/img/NPLwebsite17_header_mobile_accountBtn.png?v=34534534'>
      </div>

      <input placeholder='Username' type='text' name = 'username'>
        <div class='validation'>
          <img src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/217233/tick.png'>
        </div>
      </input>
    </div>

    <div class='login_fields__password'>
      <div class='icon'>
        <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Lock_icon.png'>
      </div>
      <input placeholder='Password' type='password' name = 'password'>
      <div class='validation'>
          </div>

    </div>
    <div class='login_fields__submit'>
      <input type='submit' formmethod="post" value='Submit'>



<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="{% static 'signup.js' %}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no `<form>` tag in your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the documentation shows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user), the signature for `create_user` is:

```
create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)
```

So you are passing the password as the email argument. Instead, use a keyword argument:

```
User.objects.create_user(username, password=password)
```

Comment: The Users model doesnt come with a passwords field, thats okay right?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Why are you setting a password if you have no password field?

Comment: no, i meant the fields in the User field in django-admin does not show a passwords field for all my users.By default It has username, email, firstname, lastname, and staff status. Why doesnt it show a password field? When i edit a user I can modify their password though. Sorry its a bit  confusing.

Comment: It doesn't show it because it's not directly editable, because Django only stores a hash not the raw value.